# How can I check the device platform before deployment in the .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile, platform, pocketpc

I've developed an application for Windows Mobile using Windows Mobile 6 Pro with CF 3.5 and I have some deployment questions.

I'm targeting only Pocket PC and I don't want to let users install it on their smartphone (because it simply won't work).

How can I check for the platform on which the user is installing the application and show him some error message?

Just to let you know, I have an .msi in order to install the app into the device from the desktop (setup project with cab inside), and it's fine.

I just need this extra verification.

Answer (score 3):

See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/22/766343.aspx) on how you can detect the platform. Cab files support an optional [setup.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx), which can be used for registering custom actions in Install init, Install exit, Uninstall init and Unistall exit. You could use the install init entry point and stop the installation or show a dialog if the platform doesn't match. This of course has to be native development.